# Errors when updating Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (Luna 4.4.2)

Tags: eclipse, repository, updates, eclipse-luna

I am getting the following errors when updating Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Version: Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2):

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.java, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.mail.glassfish,1.4.1.v201005082020
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.aspectj.runtime.source,1.7.0.20120507134200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.source,2.2.0.e36x-20120507-1400
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.source,2.2.0.e36x-20120507-1400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.core.source,2.2.0.e36x-20120507-1400
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.source,2.2.0.e36x-20120507-1400
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.xref.ui.source,2.2.0.e36x-20120507-1400
```

Components being updated (all have Version 3.7.3.2016022509xx-RELEASE):

```
Eclipse Quicksearch
Pivotal tc Server Integration for Eclipse
Pivotal tc Server Spring Insight Integration for Eclipse
Spring Dashboard
Spring IDE AJDT Integration
Spring IDE AOP Extension
Spring IDE Autowire Extension
Spring IDE Batch Extension
Spring IDE Core
Spring IDE Integration, Flex and Web Services Extension
Spring IDE Maven Support
Spring IDE Mylyn Integration
Spring IDE Security Extension
Spring IDE Spring Data Support
Spring IDE Web Flow Extension
```

I am guessing that the version 3.7.3 above coincides with the same version of Spring Tool Suite that was just released (https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/01/spring-tool-suite-3-7-3-released) Perhaps Eclipse has not yet updated its repositories accordingly?

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

---

Update on Mar 23, 2016:

I was able to partially fix this by changing the update site for AJDT. From Eclipse's main menu, select Window | Preferences | Install/Update | Available Software Sites. Locate an entry with the name "AJDT", select it, click Edit and change the location to:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/ajdt/44/dev/update
```

According to the documentation at https://www.eclipse.org/ajdt/downloads/ , this is the correct location for AJDT updates for Eclipse Luna 4.4.

Now only one error remained:

```
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,javax.mail.glassfish,1.4.1.v201005082020
```

That one was resolved by adding an Orbit update site with this link:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20140525021250/repository/
```

Note that the above R20140525021250 build is labeled for Luna and Luna SR1. The build for Luna SR2 (R20150124073747) produced yet another error:

```
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.springframework.roo.wrapping.protobuf-java-lite,2.3.0.0001
```

so, avoid it if you are using Luna SR2, unless you want to chase down an update site with repository for that component.

Comment: Don't update Luna, or any Eclipse version, ever.  Download the latest Eclipse. unzip or install, and create a **separate** workspace.  Add your Eclipse plug-ins.  Zip your customized Eclipse in case something happens to your Eclipse installation.  Carefully copy your projects over to the new workspace, testing each project one by one.  Think of your development environment as a field full of landmines.  One misstep, and your development environment is ruined forever.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Sorry, but this makes no sense to me. The Help | Check for Updates process is there for a reason (if it were as totally unreliable as you claim, why have it available at all?), and I used it successfully many times in the past, up to this point.